# Azure ML: Include additional files during model deployment

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

In my AML pipeline, I've got a model built and deployed to the AciWebservice. I now have a need to include some additional data that would be used by score.py. This data is in json format (~1mb) and is specific to the model that's built. To accomplish this, I was thinking of sticking this file in blob store and updating some "placholder" vars in the score.py during deployment, but it seems hacky.

Here are some options I was contemplating but wasn't sure on the practicality

**Option 1:**
Is it possible to include this file, during the model deployment itself so that it's part of the docker image?

**Option 2:**
Another possibility I was contemplating, would it be possible to include this json data part of the Model artifacts?

**Option 3:**
How about registering it as a dataset and pull that in the score file?

What is the recommended way to deploy dependent files in a model deployment scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few ways to accomplish this:

1. Put the additional file in the same folder as your model file, and [register](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.model.model?view=azure-ml-py#register-workspace--model-path--model-name--tags-none--properties-none--description-none--datasets-none--model-framework-none--model-framework-version-none--child-paths-none--sample-input-dataset-none--sample-output-dataset-none--resource-configuration-none-) the whole folder as the model. In this approach the file is stored alongside the model.
2. Put the file in a local folder, and specify that folder as source_directory in [InferenceConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.model.inferenceconfig?view=azure-ml-py). In this approach the file is re-uploaded every time you deploy a new endpoint.
3. Use custom base image in InferenceConfig to bake the file into Docker image itself.

Answer (score 0):

To extend the answer by @Roope Astala - MSFT, this is how you can implement it by using the second approach

> Put the file in a local folder, and specify that folder as source_directory in InferenceConfig. In this approach the file is re-uploaded every time you deploy a new endpoint.

Let's say this is your file structure.

```
.
└── deployment
    ├── entry.py
    ├── env.yml
    └── files
        ├── data.txt
```

And you want to read the `files/names.txt` in `entry.py` script.

This is how would you read it in `entry.py`:

```py
file_path = 'deployment/files/data.txt'
  with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    ...
```

And this is how you would set up your deployment configuration.

```py
deployment_config = AciWebservice.deploy_configuration(cpu_cores = 1, memory_gb = 1)
inference_config = InferenceConfig(
    runtime='python',
    source_directory='deployment',
    entry_script='entry.py',
    conda_file='env.yml'
)
```

Comment: what if i need to edit entry.py later after deployment without changing restendpoint.

Comment: @vishal You can use `overwrite=True` in the `Model.deploy` method. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.model(class)