# Include additional files during model deployment (part 2)

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

Since we're not supposed to ask questions to answered questions, I'm posting this additional question here.  It references the question/answers found here however:  [Azure ML: Include additional files during model deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61803031/azure-ml-include-additional-files-during-model-deployment)

Problem:  in my scoring script I need to reference data in a file for additional data munging before calling the model.

Option #2 referenced in that link (use InferenceConfig to specify a folder as source directory) appears to be what I need.  But when I attempt to access the included file in my scoring script, I'm getting an error message that the file doesn't exist.  I believe I've done something wrong but I'm not sure what.

My work is taking place strictly in Azure ML Studio.
I have a directory where both my scoring script and the pickle file I want to include are found.
It's also where the Jupyter Notebook script is found that's driving the creation of these things.
The pathing would look something like this:  Users->myname->myfolder

The scoring script is named score.py.  The pickle file is mypickle.pkl.

Code in score.py to read the file.  This code is found in the run() method.

```
filename="./mypickle.pkl"
df = pd.read_pickle(filename)
```

The InferenceConfig call:

```
inference_config = InferenceConfig(
environment=environment,
source_directory="./",
entry_script="./score.py"
)
```

The model deploys fine but when testing the deployed model (aka endpoint), I receive the error
"[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mypickle.pkl'"

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I found the answer when poking around the containers (in Azure Portal) created by the model deployment.

There's a value AZUREML_SOURCE_DIRECTORY which contains the path where the source_directory files are stored.

So instead of having this code in the scoring script

```
filename="./mypickle.pkl"
df = pd.read_pickle(filename)
```

It should be this code.

```
path = os.getenv('AZUREML_SOURCE_DIRECTORY') 
filename = os.path.join(path, 'mypickle.pkl')
df = pd.read_pickle(filename)
```